# How can I use the Mollie Order API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mollie

Anyone who is familliar with the Mollie API?
I am trying to set up a payment for a webshop, but I don't have much knowledge of the Mollie API.
So I got 2 questions:

1. The Order API of Mollie is like the Payment API, but the order API is a bit more "advanced" and more made for a webshop with products? Is that correct?
2. I got the following code, I assume (according to the [Mollie documentation of how a payment works](https://docs.mollie.com/payments/overview))
   that I can set up a payment (order) with an amount and [other additional information](https://docs.mollie.com/reference/v2/orders-api/create-order#payment-specific-parameters), the user will than be redirected to the Mollie platform where he can choose a payment method.

   ```
    List<OrderLineRequest> OrderLineList = new List<OrderLineRequest>();
    foreach(product in cart) {
        OrderLineRequest Orderline = new OrderLineRequest();
        Orderline.Name = B.GetProductName(ProductID);
        Orderline.Quantity = Amount;
        Orderline.UnitPrice = new Amount(Currency.EUR, ProductPrice.ToString());
        Orderline.TotalAmount = new Amount(Currency.EUR, (Amount * ProductPrice).ToString());
        Orderline.VatRate = "21.00";
        Orderline.VatAmount = new Amount(Currency.EUR, ((Amount * ProductPrice)*0,21).ToString());

       OrderLineList.Add(Orderline);
    }


    IOrderClient orderClient = new OrderClient("my API key");
    OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
    {
        Amount = new Amount(Currency.EUR, "Amount needs to be paid"),
        OrderNumber = OrderID.ToString(),
        Lines = OrderLineList,
        BillingAddress = new OrderAddressDetails()
        {
            GivenName = FirstName,
            FamilyName = LastName,
            Email = Email,
            City = City,
            Country = Country,
            PostalCode = PostalCode,
            StreetAndNumber = Street + " " + HouseNumber
        },
        RedirectUrl = "URL I want to redirect to when payment is done",
        Locale = Locale.en_US
    };
   ```

What else do I have to do for the user to be redirected to the Mollie platform to pay?

Thanks alot for taking time to read this, I hope you can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is obviously a commercial benefit of the company to help you build a system, Why not ask them?

Comment: https://github.com/Viincenttt/MollieApi